# debug loads the currentt view instead of the view specified in routeconfig Mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been working on a mvc4 solution and up until now when I pressed the debug button, the browser would open up to the /Home/Index action. no matter what class or view I was working on, it would load the default, just as specified in routeConfig.cs

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );            

    }
```

since this morning this has changed. now if I am currently working on /Home/Example and press debug, the browser opens to that instead of Home/Index.

I have no Idea what configuration I changed or what is causing this. any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with routing. It is related to the default startup page in Visual Studio.

Right click on the ASP.NET MVC project in your solution explorer and choose Properties. Then navigate to the `Web` tab and on Specific Page write `Home/Index`:

[image]

Maybe in your project you've got `Current Page` selected.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove your *.suo files? These files contain information related to the properties of the web application. You can simply right click your web app project in the solution explorer and select the properties menu item. On the properties page select the web tab on the left tab strip and select the radio button labeled "Specific Page" and leave the text box empty. This will ensure your web is always loaded at the root url during debug.